# unable to add spinner on Map Activity

Tags: android, spinner

> JAVA

```
Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

//Spinner for No_of_persons
spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),R.array.person_count,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position)+"selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

> XML

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/specificationrellay"
            android:layout_below="@+id/droplocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvseatingcapacity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Seating Capacity"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:fontFamily="casual"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/capacity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:fontFamily="casual"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"

                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvseatingcapacity"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvseatingcapacity"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:fontFamily="casual"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/realtime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10:30 AM"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:fontFamily="casual"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/time"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/capacity"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noofperson"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No.Of Persons"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:fontFamily="casual"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_selectperson"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/noofperson"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/realtime"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/select_person"
                android:fontFamily="casual"
                />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_below="@+id/noofperson"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_selectperson">
            </Spinner>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_closepopup"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/realtime"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="138dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="138dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="153dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:fontFamily="casual"
                android:text="Book"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Paste map activity xml and java code and try to format it properly

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Spinner` Class to set adapter - `Spinner.setAdapter(adapter);`

Use *spinner object* instead of class `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);`

Hope this solves the issue!

Comment: No.I tried Already this,using spinner object.Same error occurs

Comment: Error  :  Process: com.example.firstscreen, PID: 12703
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: @AniketPatil please add xml code for better understanding

Comment: Added.plz check it

Comment: check you provide right layout xml in setContentView method call?